# how can i store UITabelView Data in IPhone

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am developing chat application using xmpp server.I can send and receive messages and messages displayed in tableview.Here I problem is how can store message data in user defaults with respect to their emailds as key values and when i click specific email id then it will display conversation.can any one answer my question plz

thanks inadvance

Comment: When you say how? do you want us to give you the data structure? by the I would rather prefer using core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you need a database for storing your messages. On iOS your best option is [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005316).

Answer (score 0):

**Hello!** You ask **not correctly question** :) **UITabelView Data** has a type like **[NSArray, NSDict]**!
So you can store array or dict or smth collection in **nsuserdefaults/file/core data(realm)**

***Hope it helps!:)***